# Using a string to represent a control property and a project resource in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Can you please help me with two issues?
I want to be able to use a string to represent a control property in my code like this.

```
 Dim txtname as String = "textbox"
 txtname.Text = "whatever"
```

If the process is different for project resources, can you tell me how? I want a string to represent the name for an image in my project resources sort of like this.

```
 Dim imagename as String = "image"   
 picbox.Image = My.Resources.image
```

I looked up DirectCast and CType, but I couldn't find anything that helped me. A lot of code didn't work and didn't make sense. I'm looking for something simplified Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

You arent trying to use a string to represent a control property, but an actual Control Object.  You cant just convert a string variable into a control object.  They are 2 different things.

One way you can use a string to find a control is to use the name of it in the Controls collection:

```
Dim tb As TextBox = Me.Controls.Find("textbox name to find", True)
' if found, tb now refers to that textbox
```

Note: The True param to `Find` tells the form to search child container controls like `Tabs` and `Panels`, since the control you are looking for may actually exist in one of those other Control Collections.

For resources:

```
Dim resName As String = "FuzzyBunny"
Dim bmp as Bitmap
bmp = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resName), Bitmap)
```

The identifier has to exist and it has to be an image or Bad Things will happen.  This is of somewhat dubious value because `bmp = My.Resources.FuzzyBunny` is more straight forward and in both cases, you need to know the name/ID of the resource.